# differences between initializing int in c++ with double

Tags: c++, initialization, clion

what are the differences between this kind of initializing in c++;

```
int a = 0;
int a{};
int ();
```

why this code `int a{3.14}` get me error but this one int `a = 3.14` or this one `int a(3.14)` do not

Comment: Look up [narrowing conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Narrowing_conversions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

int a = 0; and int a(0); make no difference in the machine generated code. They are the same.

Following is the assembly code generated in Visual Studio

```
int a = 10;   // mov dword ptr [a],0Ah  
int b(10);    // mov dword ptr [b],0Ah
```

but `int a{}` is a little bit different because of narrowing conversions which prohibit some list-initializing

these are from [c++ reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Narrowing_conversions):

> Narrowing conversions
>
> list-initialization limits the allowed implicit conversions by
>   prohibiting the following:
>
> ```
> conversion from a floating-point type to an integer type 
>
> conversion from a long double to double or to float and conversion from double to float, except where the source is a constant expression
> ```
>
> and overflow does not occur
>
> ```
> conversion from an integer type to a floating-point type, except where the source is a constant expression whose value can be stored
> ```
>
> exactly in the target type
>
> ```
> conversion from integer or unscoped enumeration type to integer type that cannot represent all values of the original, except where
> ```
>
> source is a constant expression whose value can be stored exactly in
>   the target type

I wish this answer would be useful

Answer (score 4):

It's called list initialization (C++11) :

```
int foo = 0; // Initialize foo with 0
int foo{}; // Initialize foo with foo's type (int) default value, which is 0
int foo(); // Function declaration

int bar = 5.f; // Initialize bar with 5 (narrowing conversion from floating point)
int bar{5.f}; // Doesn't compile, because there is a loss of data when casting a float to an int
int bar(5.f); // Initialize bar with 5 (narrowing conversion from floating point)
```

However :

```
float f{5}; // Okay, because there is no loss of data when casting an int to a float
```

Comment: Is `int foo();` a variable creation or a function declaration?  My understanding is that it would be a function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

`a{3.14}` will throw an error because you didn't specify the [type](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_types.htm),

`int a(3.14) // initial value: 3.14, you could use {} also intead of ()` wont because you said it is integer..

I will provide you some explanation, and I hope it will be more clear to you:

```
// Bog-standard declaration.


    int a;


// WRONG - this declares a function.

    int a();

// Bog-standard declaration, with constructor arguments.
// (*)

    int a(1, 2, 3... args);

// Bog-standard declaration, with *one* constructor argument
// (and only if there's a matching, _non-explicit_ constructor).
// (**)

    int a = 1;

// Uses aggregate initialisation, inherited from C.
// Not always possible; depends on layout of T.

    int a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

// Invoking C++0x initializer-list constructor.

    int a{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

// This is actually two things.
// First you create a [nameless] rvalue with three
// constructor arguments (*), then you copy-construct
// a [named] T from it (**).

    int a = T(1, 2, 3);

// Heap allocation, the result of which gets stored
// in a pointer.

    int* a = new T(1, 2, 3);

// Heap allocation without constructor arguments.

    int* a = new T;
```

Comment: How does list initialization work for a variable capable of only one value?  For example `int a = {...}; int a{...};`

Answer (score 1):

These two lines are equivalent

```
int i = 42;
int j(42);
```

As for braced initialization, it's a C++ feature that has appeared in C++11 Standard. Because of that, it doesn't have to be compatible with C Standard, and so it comes with stricter type safety guarantees. Namely, it forbids implicit narrowing conversion.

```
int i{ 42 };
int j{ 3.14 }; // fails to compile
int k{ static_cast<int>(2.71) }; // fine
```

Hope that helps. Let me know if you need more information.